# Given a convex differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,(dis) prove $f(x) \geq x$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, logarithms, convex-analysis

I am given $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is convex, and know that it's derivative in 0 exists and that $f'(0) = 1$. Now I have to prove/disprove if $f(x) \geq x ~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt to find a counterexample goes as follows.

I know that $f$ strictly convex $\iff f'$ monotone. So I took $f(x) := - \ln(1-x)$, for which f'(0) = 1 holds and which's derivative is monotone because
$$
f'(x_1) < f'(x_2) \iff
\frac{1}{1-x_1} < \frac{1}{1-x_2} \iff
1 - x_2 < 1 - x_1 \iff x_1 < x_2
$$
Am I correct?

Comment: your $f$ is not a function on $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both the convexity and the derivative of a function are unaffected by adding a constant, it is possible to take a function satisfying all of the above properties and simply add a large enough negative constant to ensure $f(x)<x$ for some $x$.
For instance:
$$f(x)=x^2+x-100000000$$
works.